# calling class member in another class without defining new object

Tags: c++

I have to call for a member of first class in second class without defining a new object name for first class.

SO basically I have something like this:
MAIN:

```
firstClass fClass;
fClass.firstFuntion();
```

FIRST.HPP

```
class firstClass
{
public:
void firstFunction();
};
```

SECOND.HPP

```
class secondClass
{
public:
void secondFunction();
};
```

SECOND.CPP

```
void secondClass::secondFunction()
{
//first Function should be called without defining new firstClass object name
}
```

Comment: You can pass the existing `firstClass` object as an argument to the `secondFunction`.

Comment: Thanks Anon, it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the member function is not a `static` member function, you'll need an object to call the member function. There is no getting around that. How you get a valid object is up to you.

If you want to be able to call the member function without an object, make the member function a `static` member function.

Answer (score 0):

As previously suggested make it static:

```
class firstClass
{
  public:
  static void firstFunction();
};

void firstClass::firstFunction()
{
  //definition
}
```